# Как писать правильно: радоваться жизни или к жизни

Tags: грамотная-речь

...за то, что наградили нас бесценным даром - возможностью радоваться(к) жизни, быть счастливыми и свободными.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно "радоваться жизни".

Answer (score 0):

Верно. А "к жизни" можно возродиться